# Зависание при компиляции сохранённой процедуры

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-procedures

Есть процедура, с помощью которой строиться отчёт. Нужно изменить процедуру. При попытке например убрать строчку из `WHERE` или просто поменять какой нибудь символ в процедуре и дальнейшем её сохранении/компиляции SQL Developer зависает. В диспетчере задач показано что он работает, но увы. ТOAD при попытке сделать тоже самое, очень долго пытается выполнить компиляцию и не какого результата.

В чём может быть причина? Как избавиться от этого зависания?

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что процедура выполняется в данный момент. Посмотрите `DBA_DDL_LOCKS`, кажется, нет ли там вашей процедуры. Я точно не помню, вроде бы еще есть какое-то системное вью, где перечисляются заблокированные объекты.

Comment: @Dmitry а как это взглянуть? Не знаю если честно о чём вы.

Comment: `select * from DBA_DDL_LOCKS`. https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/DBA_DDL_LOCKS.htm#REFRN23051

Comment: Я с такой проблемой давно сталкивался последний раз. У меня дома лежит скрипт, который показывает всю нужную информацию, а на память я не помню.

Comment: почитайте [здесь](https://newbiedba.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/oracle-database-resolving-ddl-locks/)

Answer (score 5):

Пока процедура или функция, из пакета или без него, выполняется, её нельзя изменить.

```
create or replace procedure veryslowProc (sec number) is
begin dbms_session.sleep (sec); end;
/
```

В первой сессии:

```
SQL> exec veryslowProc (120)
```

Во второй сессии:

```
SQL> alter procedure veryslowProc compile;
```

Последний запрос зависнет, ожидая пока процедура завершится в первой сессии.

В ещё одной сессии можно узнать, в какой сессии выполняется процедура:

```
SQL> select session_id, lock_type, mode_held, mode_requested, lock_id1   
from dba_lock_internal 
where lock_id1 like upper ('%veryslow%')  
and regexp_like (lock_type, '(Table/Procedure/Type|Body) Definition Pin');
/

SESSION_ID LOCK_TYPE                              MODE_HELD  MODE_REQUE LOCK_ID1        
---------- -------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
        52 Table/Procedure/Type Definition Pin    None       Exclusive  ME.VERYSLOWPROC 
       269 Table/Procedure/Type Definition Pin    Share      None       ME.VERYSLOWPROC
```

Сессия 269 выполняет процедуру, 52 ждёт, чтобы приступить к компиляции.